# How to update row if session.add throws duplicate key error in sql alchemy ORM

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

```
    engine = db_connect()
    create_table(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    self.session = Session()

    settings = get_project_settings()
    stock_engine = create_engine(settings.get('STOCK_DATABASE_URI'), echo=True,pool_recycle=1800)
    StockSession = sessionmaker(bind=stock_engine)
    self.stock_session = StockSession()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    sleep(0.3)
    item_table.uni_identifier = item['uni_identifier']
    
    symbols = self.stock_session.execute("SELECT * from table3")
    
    for row in symbols:
        stock_table = Trial_table()
        stock_table.stock_symbol = row["symbol"]
        stock_table.company_name = row["companyName"]
        stock_table.last_updated = arrow.utcnow().to('local').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        
        self.session.add(stock_table)
        
        try:
            self.session.commit()
        except:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise

    self.session.add(item_table)
    try:
       self.session.commit()
    except:
       self.session.rollback()
       raise
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062,
> "Duplicate entry 'GNLN' for key 'trial_table.stock_symbol_UNIQUE'")

Above Error is generated at session.add(stock_table).What I want to achieve is if session.add(stock_table) generated duplicate key error I want to update instead of insert. How can I achieve this? Already tried using self.session.merge(stock_table). Its not working. Trial_table() is a ORM for respective table in database.

Answer (score 2):

For a single-threaded application, it's simplest to trap the `IntegrityError`and try an update instead (`IntegrityError`s happen when a session is committed (or flushed)).

```py
    session.add(Trial_Table(stock_symbol=symbol, company_name=company_name))
    try:
        session.commit()
    except sa.exc.IntegrityError:
        session.rollback()
        instance = session.query(Trial_Table).filter(Trial_Table.stock_symbol == symbol).first()
        instance.company_name = company_name
        try:
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
```

Ugly, but effective.

Using MySQL's "ON DUPLICATE KEY ... UPDATE" functionality would be another way.  Note that the ORM [functionality](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#orm-dml-returning-objects) is experimental.  It might look something like this (untested as my version of Mariadb does not support `RETURNING`).

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, update

...

stmt = update(Trial_Table).where(Trial_Table.stock_symbol == symbol).values(company_name=company_name).returning(Trial_Table)
orm_stmt = select(Trial_Table).from_statement(stmt).execution_options(populate_existing=True)
session.execute(orm_stmt)
try:
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
```

Alternatively, you could use SQLAlchemy core syntax to perform the [upsert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert) without having to rely on support for `RETURNING`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert
...

# Operate on the model's __table__ attribute
stmt = insert(Trial_Table.__table__).values(stock_symbol=symbol, company_name=company_name)
on_duplicate_key_stmt = stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(company_name=company_name)
session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
try:
    session.commit()
except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
```